# how to handle properly multiple exception thrower objects

Tags: java

I want to handle exceptions on higher level not in this method but I want to be sure that object a & b closed properly.

close() method can also throw an exception.

Is this template the proper solution for this or there is a smarter/simpler solution?

```
public void foo() throws Exception {
 A a = null;
 B b = null;
 try {
  a = new A();
  b = new B();
  ...
 } catch(Exception e) {
  throw e;
 }
 finally {
  Exception ex = null;
  try {
   if (a != null)
    a.close();
  } catch(Exception x){
    ex = x;
  }
  try {
   if (b != null)
    b.close();
  } catch(Exception x) {
   ex = x;
  }
  if (ex != null)
   throw ex;
 }
```

Comment: Any reason why this is tagged both [c#] and [java]?

Comment: What are you gaining by error checking on the close methods? why not have them be handled further up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A a = null;
try
{
  a = new A();
  //do stuff
}
finally
{
  a.Close();
}
```

A `try` block doesn't need a `catch` block, it needs a `catch` or `finally` block (or both).

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution to this problem (in C#) is the `using` statement:

```
using(A a = new A())
using(B b = new B())
{
    //...
}
```

This ensures that both `a` and `b` are `Dispose`d when control leaves the block.

Answer (score 1):

I see just one small problem: in case, `a.close()` and `b.close()` both fail, then the exception from `a.close()` is lost, because you reuse `ex`.

You could use a logger to persist the exception messages - in that case it could be sufficiant to just throw *any* exception in the finally block, because you've saved the error message in a log file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Besides what **Femaref** says, you can create a helper method taking one or more closable objects and throwing exception if necessary. Simply to reduce redundancy.
2. It's generally desirable to return original error message instead of the one occurred during `close` call. The later will probably follow directly from the former, but you need former to get to the real cause of the problem.